# Which event type does JVM generate when a user clicks a radio button? Is it an action event or an item event?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jradiobutton, itemlistener

I am fairly new to swing components. However, I have seen many examples where a radio button implements actionListener as well as itemListener. Which one is the correct way of handling events in such a case?

Comment: A little example why you might use both would be a radiobutton that sends a signal for as long as it is selected. You could implement an `ItemListener` for the standard left click select/deselect action, and an `ActionListener` to implement functionality for right click so that the radio button is selected as long as right click is pressed on it. You could also do all of that with an `ActionListener` only though.

Answer (score 2):

> Which event type does JVM generate when a user clicks a radio button? Is it an action event or an item event?

It depends which listener(s) has(/have) been attached to the radio buttons! E.G. Either or both of [`AbstractButton.addActionListener(ActionListener)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)) / [`addItemListener(ItemListener)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addItemListener(java.awt.event.ItemListener)).

**Aside:** for this I'd recommend an `ActionListener`.
The `ItemListener` will produce *two* events when a button in a `ButtonGroup` is selected. One of the events is for the item which just got *deselected.*